# AES simple encryption in Node and decryption in Python and vice versa

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, encryption, aes

**NODE Environment**

I generate secretKey in nodejs as below,

```
const generateAesKey = () => {
    const { randomBytes } = require('node:crypto');

    randomBytes(32, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        return buf.toString('hex');
    });

}
const secretKey = generateAesKey();
```

SecretKey looks something like this : `491fb9719864f51e19a0705a3ef2de15cd91576d881cdc4bd4394bf7451ee404`

Using above key, I encrypt and decrypt data as below (**Node** environment)

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// updated per Tppaco's comment
const secretKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("491fb9719864f51e19a0705a3ef2de15cd91576d881cdc4bd4394bf7451ee404");                                  

const encrypt = (plainText) => {

    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey), {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    });
    return encrypted.toString();

}

const decrypt = (cipherText) => {
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey), {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    });
    return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);
}

const en = encrypt("Text to be encrypted");
console.log(decrypt(en))
```

I am able to encrypt/decrypt data successfully in **Node** environment.
**The problem** comes when I have to decrypt data in **Python** environment that I encrypted in **Node** environment.

**Python Environment**

I have written below **Python** code which is equivalent Node code (correct me if this statement is not right).

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad,unpad
import base64
import json
import os
#CBC with Fix IV

# key = os.urandom(32)                                 // to generate random secret key

# updated per Tppaco's comment
key = bytes.fromhex('491fb9719864f51e19a0705a3ef2de15cd91576d881cdc4bd4394bf7451ee404')


data = 'Text to be encrypted'

#FIX IV
iv =  'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB'.encode('utf-8') #16 char for AES128

def encrypt(data,key,iv):
        data= pad(data.encode(),16)
        cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(data))

def decrypt(enc,key,iv):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc),16)



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    encrypted = encrypt(data,key,iv)
    print('encrypted CBC base64 : ',encrypted.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))

    decrypted = decrypt(encrypted,key,iv)
    print('decrypted data: ', decrypted.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'decrypted text': json.dumps(decrypted.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
    }
```

**Error**

> "errorMessage": "Padding is incorrect.",
> "errorType": "ValueError",

My main purpose is to encrypt data in **Node** and decrypt it in **Python**. What am I doing wrong ?

Please help. I really need a solution. Been trying to resolve since many days...

Comment: The key 491f... is hex encoded and must therefore be hex decoded before use. However, this does not happen in the CryptoJS code, instead the key is UTF-8 encoded, resulting in a key that is too long (64 bytes). CryptoJS should actually throw an error message, but due to a bug it does not. The generated ciphertext is not AES compliant and cannot be decrypted with any AES compliant library. The Python side behaves correctly and throws an error message when the invalid 64 bytes key is applied.

Comment: This is the CryptoJS bug mentioned above: issue [#293](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293). Since CryptoJS is [discontinued](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js?tab=readme-ov-file#discontinued), this will probably never be fixed.

Comment: Then what is the alternate ?

Comment: You simply need to apply a valid key in the CryptoJS code. Since your key 491f... is hex encoded, you must use the [hex encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders): `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(secretKey)`, which results in a 32 bytes key (corresponding to AES-256). Note that the ciphertexts generated with the invalid key cannot be decrypted (or only with CryptoJS), as they are not AES-compliant. In the Python code, the key must of course also be hex decoded (e.g. with `bytes.fromhex()`).

Comment: Could you help me with an example or if you can write an answer? As I'm unable to understand what you say. That would be helpful for me to move forward.

Comment: @Topaco I tried what you said and I updated my question as per your suggestion. You can check my question again. Now I get different error about padding. could you pls help? I guess now only minor thing is missing.

Comment: Since `secretKey` is the raw key (you have already performed the hex decoding in the 2nd line of the NodeJS code), `secretKey` must be passed *directly* in `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` (i.e. without UTF-8 encoding), e.g. `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secretKey, {...})`.

Comment: Note that a static IV is a vulnerability. Instead, a random IV should be generated during encryption. This is not secret and is passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext (generally concatenated).

Comment: Yes, finally it works after your instructions. You can write an answer. I'll accept it.